# In django redirect every user to different pages depending on username

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect

I am developing a django web-application, for authorization I have used **django.contrib.auth.urls**, is there a way that after authentication I can redirect user to a url like **/myapp/history/{{ username }}**. I tried couple of methods along with class-based views and login decorators but no luck. Any help would be really great. Thanks 
Note that I don't want different redirections for user and admin instead I want different redirection for each client.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not defining a method view and then an redirect to

```
url = '/myapp/history/%s' % (request.user.username())
```

You could define this view as

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/mydirector/'
```

in settings.py

Comment: hey thanks that helped.                                                                        `class node_check(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
    def get(self,request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
               reverse('/myapp/history/%s/' % (request.user.username) ))`              The above method gives a url **myapp/history/username/** but the reverse method gives error however if I enter url as the page shows.